# what is the algorithm for going around anti clockwise

Tags: algorithm

I was able to make an algorithm for going around clockwise: 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 ...
It's like this:

```
(i % 4) + 1
```

Now I need to do the opposite thing: 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 ...

Can you please help me, this is making me mad. :D

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
 5 - ((i % 4) + 1)
```

seems to do the trick. May not be optimal but it works

Answer (score 2):

Try the following formula for anti clockwise values

> 4-(i % 4)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your "clockwise" series - you'll note the "counterclockwise" series is always five minus the corresponding clockwise value. Thus,

```
5 - ((i % 4) + 1)
```

should work. The parentheses may be omitted as well in most languages as `%` is typically performed before addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it wasn't mentioned here, but there's no real reason to subtract anything (I personally think it's less readable that way) - an addition modulo can do the same -

```
(i + 3) % 4
```

In general -

```
(i + (N-1)) % N
```

Or for going back any arbitrary step `m` -

```
(i + (N-m)) % N
```